# Mac Terminal "reset"command

Tags: macos, terminal, ncurses, xterm

**

How to use command reset -w to get a new resized window?

**

```
sheng:~ Mck$ reset -h
reset: illegal option -- h
Usage: tset [options] [terminal]

Options:
-c          set control characters
-e ch       erase character
-I          no initialization strings
-i ch       interrupt character
-k ch       kill character
-m mapping  map identifier to type
-Q          do not output control key settings
-r          display term on stderr
-s          output TERM set command
-V          print curses-version
-w          set window-size
```

I've tried this and it did not work at all:

```
reset: can't initialize terminal type 40*40 (error -1)
Terminal type? 40,40
reset: can't initialize terminal type 40,40 (error -1)
Terminal type? (40,40)
reset: can't initialize terminal type (40,40) (error -1)
Terminal type?
```

## ***So what on earth should I input?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`reset`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html) (an ncurses utility) does not *do* that.  Some terminals respond to the *dtterm* escape sequences (such as xterm and imitators) used in [**`resize`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) (an xterm utility):

```
resize -s 40 40
```

For what it's worth: Terminal.app and **iTerm** recognize the sequences.  iTerm2 also does, but the feature is normally disabled (look in *Preferences*, *Terminal*).  On other platforms, you would see differences.